# Saints Row 3 (The third) Comes with most of the things done for me

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I recently bought the whole PC series of Saints Row and after I began the third, after I leveled up, I saw that most of the power upgrades were already done for me and many clothing items were already bought.

I know the game is quite easy  economically but I want to start a game in which I can actually level up, not sideways.

Is it possible to begin a game in which (preferably) everything is locked?

I probably have all the downloadables of the game.

Comment: Did you get any DLC and what upgrades did you see were "done" for you?  I don't remember the base game giving me too much free stuff, so not sure why this is happening to you.

Comment: Yes, it's the DLCs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Right click on "Saints Rows: The Third" in your list of games in your library and select "Properties". Click on the on the DLC tab and search for the entries called "Saints Row: The Third - Unlockable Pack" and "Saints Row: The Third - Bloodsucker Pack". Uncheck the boxes next to them and these DLCs will no longer be active. Unfortunately you may have to start a new character as your existing character already has everything unlocked.

Unfortunately I don't have the "Saints Row: The Third - Unlockable Pack", but here's what the DLC list looks like:
[image: Saints Rows 3 Steam DLC list]

Note that many clothing items and certain weapons and vehicles that are enabled by the other DLCs will remain. You can also disable these DLCs as well, but there's no way to unlock their content in the game. If you want to use them you'll need to have the DLC active. Since you can simply not use any of these thing if you think they make the game unfun I would just leave all the other DLCs entries checked.

Comment: @altac I've updated my answer with one other DLC you probably want to disable: "Saints Row: The Third - Bloodsucker Pack". I don't have this DLC either, but according the reviews it also unlocks a bunch of powers  that you can't simply choose to not use.

Comment: I disabled the DLC this way and steam says it's not installed and i began a new game but still, all the bonus upgrades are unlocked. People drop four times money and i have every bonus cash and respect upgrade checked regardless of their required level.

Comment: @altacbori Did you also disable the "Saints Row: The Third - Bloodsucker Pack" DLC? I had overlooked this DLC in my initial answer.

Comment: Yes, disabling the bloodsucker pack worked for me. Thanks.