# Permanently disabling Saints Row: The Third DLC on Steam

Tags: steam, saints-row-the-third

I bought Saints Row: The Third PC on Steam with a load of DLC which unlocks way too many things from the start, so I'd like to disable the DLC. I found that this can be done by right clicking on the game in my Steam Library, going to "View Downloadable Content" and clearing the checkboxes in the "Install" column for each DLC. This worked great the first time, but the next time I start Steam I find that all of the DLC has been re-installed and I have to go remove it again.

It looks like some people are using a similar process without the same complaint: 
[Saints Row 3 (The third) Comes with most of the things done for me](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/208802/saints-row-3-the-third-comes-with-most-of-the-things-done-for-me). This isn't a duplicate, it's a further problem where I disable the DLC and it keeps getting re-installed automatically when Steam restarts.

Is there a way to uninstall the DLC, and keep it uninstalled until I want to re-install it?

Comment: Try uninstalling the game, unchecking all the boxes, then installing the game again.

Comment: I've been running into this as well; the last time I uninstalled the DLC it's kept so far.  The only thing I can think of that's been done differently is that I haven't recently started up Steam on a different box (usually I end up streaming to a TV so my wife can be entertained with my poor driving skills).  Haven't done anything rigorous to test this though, so see if that's it; if it is, I'll post as an answer, if not, well someone else should be able to help.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness - Not a duplicate.  Linked question addresses the issue with DLC making the game easy, and disabling it.  Above question is following that answer, and finding something is turning DLC back on.  Separate issue, which I've run into myself.

Comment: @Thebluefish - Thanks, that's the answer. I uninstalled Saints Row: The Third ("Delete local content..."), cleared the checkboxes in the DLC tab, reinstalled the game and now the DLC stays uninstalled. My save survived the process too. Would you like to post your solution as an Answer so you get credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Steam option controls "installing" the DLC. So to clear it up:

- Uninstall Saints Row 3
- Uncheck the boxes to disable the DLC
- Install Saints Row 3